# Нужна помощь с синтезом типа

Tags: функции, типы, haskell, type-error, типизация

Есть следующая функция, которая создаёт логическую функцию, опираясь на вектор значений:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiWayIf #-}

buildFnFromVec lst 
    | length lst == 4 =
                    \x -> \y -> if
                              | (x == False && y == False) -> lst !! 0
                              | (x == False && y == True) -> lst !! 1
                              | (x == True && y == False) -> lst !! 2
                              | (x == True && y == True) -> lst !! 3
    | length lst == 8 =
                    \x -> \y -> \z -> if
                               | (x == False && y == False && z == False) -> lst !! 0
                               | (x == False && y == False && z == True) -> lst !! 1
                               | (x == False && y == True && z == False) -> lst !! 2
                               | (x == False && y == True && z == True) -> lst !! 3
                               | (x == True && y == False && z == False) -> lst !! 4
                               | (x == True && y == False && z == True) -> lst !! 5
                               | (x == True && y == True && z == False) -> lst !! 6
                               | (x == True && y == True && z == True) -> lst !! 7
    | otherwise = error "не реализовано"
```

Как видно, возвращаемое значение меняется в зависимости от длины вектора. Я не знаю, как подобрать/сделать такой тип, чтобы компилятор перестал "ругаться". Помогите и направьте, пожалуйста. Заранее спасибо!

**EDIT:**

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiWayIf #-}

cartSelfProd :: (Monad m, Num a, Enum a) => m b -> a -> m [b]
cartSelfProd l n = mapM (\_ -> l) [1..n]


buildFnFromVec lst 
    | (\n -> elem n $ map (2^) [1..n]) (length lst) = 
        if
            | (length lst == 4) ->
                \x -> \y -> (!!) lst $ fromJust $ elemIndex [x, y] $ cartSelfProd [False, True] 2

            | (length lst == 8) ->
                \x -> \y -> \z -> (!!) lst $ fromJust $ elemIndex [x, y, z] $ cartSelfProd [False, True] 3

            | otherwise -> error "не реализовано"

    | otherwise = error "вектор некорректной длины"
```

Comment: Что должно происходить если вызвать эту функцию так: `buildFnFromVec [1,2,3,4] True False False` ?

Comment: Забыл отметить, у lst тип [Bool]. `buildFnFromVec [True, False, False, False] False False` вернёт `True`

Comment: Тем не менее. Что должно происходить при `buildFnFromVec [True, True, True, True] True True True` ?

Comment: При том, что вы ввели - ошибка, ибо слишком много аргументов.

Comment: Ошибка во время компиляции или во время исполнения?

Comment: 2 в степени количества аргументов у возвращаемой функции == length lst. Так если вектор длины 4, то у функции будет два аргумента. Если 8, то три аргумента. 16 -- 4 и так далее.

Comment: Ошибка когда должна происходить - во время компиляции или во время исполнения?

Comment: Во время компиляции. Аппликация Bool к Bool произойдёт.

Comment: Ок, тогда следующий вопрос: что если список считывается из файла или с консоли, или как-то так? Неизвестен список во время компиляции.

Comment: Список известен во время компиляции.

Comment: Ок, ясно. Сейчас отвечу.

Comment: Снова привет, кстати =)

Answer (score 0):

Согласно вашим комментариям:

- Список `lst` известен во время компиляции
- Если количество аргументов не соответствует длине списка, должна происходить ошибка компиляции

---

В языке Haskell (как, впрочем, и в любом другом языке) значения могут быть известны только во время исполнения. В этом и есть весь их смысл: они могут быть считаны с консоли, из файла, приняты из сети, и т.п. Знать их заранее, до исполнения программы, невозможно.

Во время компиляции могут быть известны только *типы*. Например, точно известно, что значение считанное из файла - это текстовая строка. Какая именно строка (т.е. *значение*) заранее неизвестно, но точно известно, что строка (т.е. *тип*).

Следовательно, для того, чтобы обеспечить известность списка `lst` во время компиляции, необходимо, чтобы он был не значением, а именно *типом*.

Как так? Как список может быть типом? Что это вообще значит?! Дальше пойдут продвинутые темы, так что пристегните ремни.

---

Когда-то давным-давно имелось в виду, что "тип" - это "тип данных" - то есть "целое число", "строка", "дата" и т.п. Типы тогда соответствовали математическим "множествам". Буквально: "тип - это множество возможных значений переменной". Но со временем выяснилось, что есть и другие конструкции, которые ведут себя почти как типы. Возьмите, к примеру, `Maybe`. Это тип или нет? В "старом" значении, конечно нет: не может быть значений типа `Maybe`. Могут быть значения типа `Maybe Int` или `Maybe String`, но значений самого типа `Maybe` быть не может. И тем не менее `Maybe` ведёт себя во многом как тип. Например, он может быть шаблонным аргументом.

Современный Haskell позволяет вертеть типами в очень широких пределах (далеко до Idris, но всё же). В частности, возможна такая штука как "список на уровне типов". Как-то вот так:

```
type T = '[Int, String]
```

Этот тип-список, состоящий из двух типов-элементов - `Int` и `String`. Одинарная кавычка - это специальный синтаксис, чтобы не путать уровень значений, уровень типов, и уровень видов (kinds).

Кроме того, Haskell позволяет автоматически "поднимать" алгебраические конструкторы на уровень типов, делая каждый конструктор самостоятельным типом. Например:

```
data F a = F  -- аргумент "a" - фантомный, то есть не используется в конструкторе

x :: F Int  -- инстанциирование F с параметром Int
x = F

y :: F Maybe  -- инстанциирование F с параметром Maybe
y = F

z :: F True  -- инстанциирование F с параметром True. Здесь конструктор True "поднят" и стал типом
z = F
```

Для этого нужно расширение `DataKinds`.

---

Аналогом функций на уровне типов являются *семейства типов* (type families) и классы. Семейства типов могут вычислять только типы из других типов (так же как обычные функции могут вычислять значения из других значений), но в вашем случае нужно вычислить не только тип функции, но и её значение, поэтому следует воспользоваться классом:

```
class DefineFn (lst :: [Bool]) fn | lst -> fn where
  fn :: fn
```

Класс `DefineFn` имеет два параметра (нужно расширение `MultiParamTypeClasses`). Первый, `lst` - это тип-список, состоящий из типов вида `Bool`. Запись `:: [Bool]` здесь - это деклапация *вида* (kind signature). Второй параметр - `fn` - это тип функции, которая может работать со списком `lst`. Запись `| lst -> fn` - это *функциональная зависимось* (нужно расширение `FunctionalDependencies`), которая утверждает, что каждому списку `lst` соответствует только одна функция `fn`.

Теперь для такого класса можно написать реализации. Начнём с одного случая, самого простого:

```
instance DefineFn '[False, False, False, False] (Bool -> Bool -> Bool) where
  -- Возвращает False независимо от параметров, потому что все элементы списка - False
  fn _ _ = False
```

Протестируем:

```
> fn @'[False, False, False, False] True True
False

> fn @'[False, False, False, False] True True True
Ошибка: нет реализации DefineFn для списка [False, False, False, False] и функции (Bool -> Bool -> Bool -> a)
```

Символ `@` означает "видимую передачу типа" (нужно расширение `TypeApplications`) - когда я сам пишу какой тип здесь нужен, а не даю компилятору это выяснить самостоятельно. Тем более что в данном случае он этого сделать не сможет. В этом весь и смысл: я специально написал класс таким образом, чтобы вручную передавать список.

Аналогично можно написать и другие реализации:

```
instance DefineFn '[True, False, False, False] (Bool -> Bool -> Bool) where
  fn False False = True
  fn _ _ = False

instance DefineFn '[True, True, False, False] (Bool -> Bool -> Bool) where
  fn False False = True
  fn False True = True
  fn _ _ = False
```

М-да... Но так можно и запариться: таких реализаций будет аж 16. А для восьмиэлементного списка - так и вовсе 256!

---

Но есть способ сократить их общее количество до четырёх: вместо того, чтобы прямо перечислять элементы списка как `True` и `False`, сделаем их параметрами:

```
instance DefineFn '[a, b, c, d] (Bool -> Bool -> Bool) where
  fn x y = case (x, y) of
    (False, False) -> a
    (False, True) -> b
    (True, False) -> c
    (True, True) -> d
```

Вроде всё складно: в зависимости от параметров функции, возвращаем тот или иной элемент списка. Да вот незадача: это не компилируется. Почему? Потому что `a`, `b`, `c` и `d` - это типы, а не значения, и потому вернуть их из функции нельзя. Что же делать?

Но мы ведь уже умеем делать функции "из типов в значения"! Можно и воспользоваться этим умением:

```
class BoolTypeToValue (b :: Bool) where
    boolTypeToValue :: Bool
instance BoolTypeToValue True where
    boolTypeToValue = True
instance BoolTypeToValue False where
    boolTypeToValue = False
```

Этот класс и его реализации позволяют преобразовать тип вида `Bool` в соответствующее значние типа `Bool`:

```
> boolTypeToValue @True
True
> boolTypeToValue @False
False
```

Теперь можно записать реализацию `DefineFn` так:

```
instance 
  ( BoolTypeToValue a
  , BoolTypeToValue b
  , BoolTypeToValue c
  , BoolTypeToValue d
  ) => DefineFn '[a, b, c, d] (Bool -> Bool -> Bool) 
 where
  fn x y = case (x, y) of
    (False, False) -> boolTypeToValue @a
    (False, True) -> boolTypeToValue @b
    (True, False) -> boolTypeToValue @c
    (True, True) -> boolTypeToValue @d
```

И аналогично для восьмиэлементного списка:

```
instance 
  ( BoolTypeToValue a
  , BoolTypeToValue b
  , BoolTypeToValue c
  , BoolTypeToValue d
  , BoolTypeToValue e
  , BoolTypeToValue f
  , BoolTypeToValue g
  , BoolTypeToValue h
  ) => DefineFn '[a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h] (Bool -> Bool -> Bool -> Bool) 
 where
  fn x y z = case (x, y, z) of
    (False, False, False) -> boolTypeToValue @a
    (False, False, True) -> boolTypeToValue @b
    (False, True, False) -> boolTypeToValue @c
    (False, True, True) -> boolTypeToValue @d
    ...
```

---

В заключении хочу также отметить, что всё это вам, *скорее всего*, не нужно. Если это просто из теоретического любопытства, или, допустим, ну, я не знаю, чтобы показать какой Haskell плохой и неудобный язык по сравнению, допустим, с Python (ну, чисто гипотетически), - то конечно. См. мой ответ выше в таком случае.

Но если это всё вам нужно для какой-то практической цели, то это из пушки по воробьям. На практике 99% программ не нуждаются в таких усложнениях. Если хотите сделать "так же как в Python" - то и сделайте именно так же: передавайте параметры в виде списка длина которого не опрделена во время компиляции, как-то так:

```
fn lst args
    | length lst == 4 = case args of
        [False, False] -> lst !! 0
        [False, True] -> lst !! 1
        [True, False] -> lst !! 2
        [True, True] -> lst !! 3
        _ -> "Неправильное количество аргументов"
    ...
```

А если у вас какая-то реальная практическая задача, для которой вы хотите использовать такую функцию, то я могу вам сразу сказать 100%, что вашу задачу можно решить проще, надёжнее и эффективнее.

Основное что нужно осознать: у разных языков программирования разные "типичные решения" для одних и тех же проблем, и самое простое и очевидное решение из одного языка может вовсе не работать в другом. Ну или плохо будет работать.

Comment: > Если количество аргументов не соответствует длине списка, должна происходить ошибка компиляции. Количество аргументов и не должно соответствовать длине списка. Список -- это вектор значений булевой функции, из которых восстанавливается сама функция.

Comment: Зависимость между длиной списка и количеством аргументов в возвращаемой функции я описал.

Comment: Слова "соответствует" и "равно" - это разные слова. Я специально использовал слово "соответствует", а не "равно".

Comment: Понял, тогда всё так, да

Comment: Вы, похоже, не совсем поняли, как задаётся соответствие аргументов элементам списка. Представьте таблицу истинности. 00 - первый элемент списка. 01 -- второй. И так далее. Так что в последнем код-блоке fn True True должен вернуть False.

Comment: Да, это опечатка. Там должно было быть `fn False False = True`. Исправил.

Comment: Так, окей. Но 4 элемента в списке и 2 аргумента в возвращаемой функции -- только один случай. Есть ещё второй, где 8 элементов и 3 аргумента. Как быть?

Comment: Если это поможет, я подредактировал функцию `buildFnFromVec`

Comment: Для второго случая - написать вторую реализацию класса разумеется - `DefineFn '[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h] (Bool -> Bool -> Bool -> Bool) where ...`
В этом и смысл классов: одна функция на разных типах

Comment: Не, меня не интересует показ того, какой Haskell "не удобный". Я просто хочу узнать, можно ли в типе задать что-то вроде  `(Callable f) => [Bool] -> f`, чтобы я мог возвращать функцию с неоднозначным типом в зависимости от значения. Если нельзя и в любом случае нужно идти на такие изощрения, то это печально.

Comment: Ну, или тогда как лучше сделать, чтобы избежать таких "огородов" из классов? Или можно ли как-то объявить возможные типы функции и на этом успокоиться?

Comment: Это опять слишком широко и неопределенно. Зачем именно вам нужно иметь такую функцию? Как я уже написал, я уверен на 100%, что для решения вашей конкретной задачи это не нужно.